# Find orientation dependant UIView frame without rotation using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, screen-rotation

I'm using autolayout for an app I'm building. Everything is working well for rotation and all the views are transforming perfectly on all devices.

However I need to know what the frame of one view will be for all possible orientations at the appearing of that view. It is dependant of its content and its superview, which is dependant of many other views as well as device orientation.
Basically I need to know which of the two frames of that particular will be bigger in size and how many times bigger will be.

So... is there any way to inspect the rotated layout without rotating the device and without hardcoding sizes for frames for all possible devices.

Thanks